# connect from nodejs to arangodb3 using unix file socket

Tags: node.js, arangodb, arangojs

I'm trying to connect to arangodb3 using Nodejs 7.5.0 with unix file socket on Gentoo Linux.

I started arrangodb3 server with a unix socket at /tmp/mysocket.

I tried two different modules:

```
const arangojs = require('arangojs');

let db = arangojs({
  url: `unix:///tmp/mysocket`,
    databaseName: false // don't automatically append database path to URL
    });

db.createDatabase('mydb', function (err, info) {
    if (err) console.error(err.stack);
    else {
    console.info('database created');
        // database created
    }
});
```

which gives me:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1023:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
```

so it tries to connect to localhost port 80, ignores my unix socket file location

I also tried:

```
var arango = require('arango');

var db = arango.Connection("unix:///tmp/mysocket");

 db.collection.list().done(function(res){
   console.log("collections: %j", res);
   });
```

which gives me:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'unix'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Xhr (/home/ufk/work-projects/bingo/arrango/node_modules/arango/lib/xhr.js:23:12)
    at Arango.request (/home/ufk/work-projects/bingo/arrango/node_modules/arango/lib/arango.js:166:2)
    at Arango.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/ufk/work-projects/bingo/arrango/node_modules/arango/lib/arango.js:204:14)
    at Object.list (/home/ufk/work-projects/bingo/arrango/node_modules/arango/lib/api/collection/index.js:125:16)
    at Object.instance.(anonymous function) [as list] (/home/ufk/work-projects/bingo/arrango/node_modules/arango/lib/api/api.js:121:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ufk/work-projects/bingo/arrango/index2.js:5:16)
```

I don't really care which module to use.. just looking for something that supports unix file sockets. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a bug report on arrangojs regarding lack support of unix file socket. they responded that it's not supported. that `unix://` is not supported yet but nodejs's `http.request` support `socketPath` parameter.

- the issue: https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/issues/405
- socketPath related documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html